# Jquery extend width of point while incrementing through a while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i;
    while($(".loader .point").width() < $(window).width()) {
        i++;
        $(".loader .point").css("width", $(".loader .point").width() + 5);
    }
});
```

I've tried to make use of the

```
setTimeout(function() { /*action*/ }, i * 100);
```

and the

```
delay(i * 100);
```

but none of these seem to achieve anything and the page just sits trying to process the above `setTimeout` function until it times out, if I use `delay` there is no delay between incrementations meaning that the point extends to the width of the window immediately.

Any ideas guys? Thanks!

Comment: You know jQuery has an animate method ?

Comment: To further clarify the reason I don't want to use jQuery's animate is because I want to increment in stages of 5px, rather than a fluid animation.

Comment: Have you tried updating your increment in the `jQuery.animate step` option?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pile up a bunch of CSS changes in a loop like that. The browser will not do any actual layout updates until the code finishes. You can put the changes in a timeout handler that resets itself until the termination conditions are met, something like

```
$(function() {
  var $point = $(".loader .point"),
      windowWidth = $(window).width();

  function expand() {
    var pw = $point.width();
    console.log("pw " + pw);
    if (pw >= windowWidth)
      return;
    $point.width((pw + 5) + "px");
    setTimeout(expand, 500);
  }

  expand();
});
```

Note that the code only looks for the "point" element once, which is 
generally a good habit to develop.

[Here's a working codepen.](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/YPMzpx)